# Monotonicity of $2^x-x-1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the function $g(x) := 2^x-x-1$ is strictly increasing on $(1, \infty)$. Using its derivative I was able to conclude that it is increasing on that interval. So, the problem is now reduced to showing that $g$ is injective.

So far I haven't been able to prove this. It might be simple, but I cannot see it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $g' >0$ implies that $g$ is strictly increasing....

Comment: @N.S.: OMG, missed that one... incredible.

Comment: Beating a dead horse: if "$g'>0$" does not satisfy whoever is asking, use the Mean Value Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g'(x)=2^x\cdot ln2-1>0$ for every $x\in(1,\infty)$ and because $g'(x)>0$ and not $g'(x)\geq 0$ we have that $g$ is strictly increasing.